# Slack bot to download files using private_url

Tags: python, bots, slack, slack-api

I'm developing a slack bot that takes images from a slack channel and uploads them to AWS S3. The Slack docs say it's possible to download a file using the private_url and an auth token but running the code redirects the bot to a sign up page instead of the file even with auth headers set.

Code used

```
import os

slack_token = 'token'
url = 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T04LKR03H8F-F04NP55S78Q/download/instagram_story_-_2.png'

res = requests.get(url, headers={f'Authorization': 'Bearer {slack_token}'})
res.raise_for_status()

with open('instagram_story_-_2.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: Does the token you're using have the `files:read` scope and is currently a member of the channel in which the file appeared in (and/or was the token the creator of the file)?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a map with two different strings you need to apply formatting to the value, not to the key.

Like this:

```py
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {slack_token}'})
```

Note the changed position of the `f`, which applies the needed functional change described above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem, please provide any textual information as text (i.e. not only as a picture of text). Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].